# How to spy a module which is loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, requirejs, jasmine

I am in the following situation.
The code (3) works with the code (1) but not with the code (2).
IMH, the reason is because the backendController module in case (2) is loaded asynchronously after the code (3).
How should I fix the code (3) to make it working with the code (2)?

P.S.:
The reason of uging the code (2) is because it makes the page loading faster.

---

(1)

```
define([
 '../../utils/backendController'    
], function (backendController) {

    events: { 
        'submit form': 'submitForm'
    },

    submitForm: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // in this way I can spy backendController object
        this.doSubmitForm(backendController);

        // in this way I can not spy backendController object
        // require(['../../utils/backendController', this.doSubmitForm); 
        // see the code (2)

    }
});
```

---

(2)

```
define([], function () {

    events: { 
        'submit form': 'submitForm'
    },

    submitForm: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // in this way I can not spy backendController object
        require(['../../utils/backendController', this.doSubmitForm);

    }
});
```

---

(3)

```
(function () {
    define([
        'backendController'
    ], function () {
        describe('when submitting a form', function () {
            beforeEach(function () {
                var mySpy = spyOn(backendController, 'myCall').andCallThrough();
                this.view.$el.find('form').submit();
            })
            it('backendController.myCall should be called', function () {
                expect(backendController.myCall.toHaveBeenCalled());
            });
        });
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you know already why (1, 3) works, in any case it does because the `backendController` module is loaded and defined before the code in (3) executes.

In case (2) what happens is that `backendController` is only required when the form is submitted. So by the time the

```
var mySpy = spyOn(backendController, 'myCall').andCallThrough();
```

spy is created, `backendController` is `undefined` ;)

Now you *could* but shouldn't adapt your code (2) by doing something like

1. create a deffered in `submitForm` that resolves in `doSubmitForm` or
2. leave (2) as is and adapt your test to require `backendController`

but that would be overkill. You should just follow the recommended way of requiring as in (1), which also has some other advantages, like for instance that you can use the `r.js` optimizer.